# Tornado Websocket "error: Authentication missing"

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

So I've got redis feature and tornado running on my server and whenever I open my websocket chat through a login, the terminal displays the following message

```
Error: Authentication missing
```

I'm not sure why this is happening because there are cookies in the authentication part of the app,

```
# Save user when authentication was successful.

    def on_user_find(result, user=user):
        #@todo: We should check if email is given even though we can assume.
        if result == "null" or not result:
            # If user does not exist, create a new entry.
            self.application.client.set("user:" + user["email"], tornado.escape.json_encode(user))
        else:
            # Update existing user.
            # @todo: Should use $set to update only needed attributes?
            dbuser = tornado.escape.json_decode(result)
            dbuser.update(user)
            user = dbuser
            self.application.client.set("user:" + user["email"], tornado.escape.json_encode(user))

        # Save user id in cookie.
        self.set_secure_cookie("user", user["email"])
        self.application.usernames[user["email"]] = user.get("name") or user["email"]
```

And in the websocket.py (where I run the script) I've made it so that the websocket handle checks if there are cookies available first before user access the app,

```
class ChatSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self, user):
        self.login = self.get_secure_cookie("user")
        if not self.login:
#            self.login = "anonymous"
             print "Not authorized"
             self.disconnect()
            return
```

Yet it's still displaying the error, I've searched online and checked several SO answers but they don't show any solid solution in regards to this question. So far the most I've gotten is that I have to access the websocket header to put the above code inside, but I have no clue how I would do that. Help?

Comment: The message "Authentication missing" does not appear in Tornado; it must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Hey I figured where the message is coming from: http://prntscr.com/53cmu2 What could possibly be going wrong? The cookies should be working as I have assigned cookie to user id in login: http://prntscr.com/53cnwp